# rsync just adds files and directories with new names to existing backup

Tags: rsync, backup

While backing up my `$HOME` with this command

```
rsync -AEgHloprtXv --specials --quiet /source/* /destination
```

I recognized that `rsync`

1. added folders regarding them as new dirs when their name was changed between two backups.
2. didn't save files when their content, but not the name had changed between two backups.

I'd like to have a backup-tool for CLI which updates files, which have changed between two backups in their content, attributes/metadata or name and removes those which are no more existent.

So to say, I'm looking for a CLI-backup-tool which makes two subdirectories identical with minimal effort.

Comment: `rsync` is not a backup tool, it's a file copying tool.  `borgbackup` is a backup tool.

Comment: What type of filesystem are you copying to?

Comment: @roaima I copy from ext4 to ext4. The destination is encrypted, that shouldn't make any difference, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overcomplicated your command. Assuming a full-featured filesystem you could use something like

```
rsync -aHXA --delete /source/ /destination/
```

However, if the system dies while the copy is in progress, you will end up with a mixed copy of old and new files. If you want to create backups, I would recommend a solution that builds on top of `rsync`, such as `rsnapshot`.